# Magento 2 product, category, cms page URL Suffix to /

Tags: magento2

How can I change the product, category and cms pages URL Suffix to /.

I want to remove .html and add /

Example.

http://domainname.com/product-name/

I know, I can remove .html from Stores->configuration->Catalog -> Product URL Suffix, I am unable to add / for html in that.

Also I know, I can fix that from Url rewrite in Back-end.

Is there are any other best way to do this in Magento2 ?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes you can do it but for that you need to create another router for it.**
You can add '/' from admin panel.It will add '/' in url, but when you will open it then will throw 404 error.
Beacuse magento trims '/' from requested url then starts searching for it in url rewrite table. As '/' is removed from requested table so it will never find it.
You can see
**vendor/magento/module-url-rewrite/Controller/Router.php**
function getRewrite : you will see trim($requestPath, '/') if you will remove trim then it will start working properly.

So, For doing it in best way you can create another router and can use same content as "Router.php".Only you need to remove trim function.